# HFS+ Mount Encrypted programmatically

Tags: macos, encryption, terminal, aes, osx-mavericks

I'm writing a little utility to manage mounted drives, but I have run into a small issue when mounting a encrypted disk, The program tells me theres no mountable file systems when I run:

```
echo "password" | hdiutil attach -stdinpass /dev/disk2s2
```

I have tried using mount_hfs , however the mount_hfs only pops up with the system password prompt. I want to use my programs' database, not the Apple keychain for the encryption code. I've seen many ways to do this exact process, but on OS X Mavericks, I'm unsure how to correct the error. I have also tried as one web page suggested, remove the "-stdinpass" parameter, as that worked for them.

How do I mount a encrypted disk using terminal utilities on OS X Mavericks. If it helps, the disk that I am testing this on is AES encrypted.

Here is a sample:

```
set passList to words of (do shell script "cat pwd.lst")
repeat with i in passList
    do shell script "Testing password: " & i
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of i & " | hdiutil attach -stdinpass     /dev/disk2s2"

end repeat
```

Comment: I added my sample code, this is in applescript, but shell or any other scripting is fine. It's mostly this command I think that is failing: hdiutil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hdiutil` is for managing disk images, not native volumes -- it has a few features that work with native volumes as well, but this isn't one of them. In general, you want `diskutil` for working with actual disks. In the case of encrypted volumes, they're managed by CoreStorage, so you actually need `diskutil cs` and its subcommands. The command you need is something like:

```
echo "password" | diskutil cd UnlockVolume 3F34630B-FAD5-4210-8812-973C158C9892 -stdinpass
```

... where 3F34630B-FAD5-4210-8812-973C158C9892 is the UUID of the volume you want to mount. If you don't know that UUID, just the /dev entry, you have some work to do. Core Storage is set up to take one or more physical volumes (e.g. /dev/disk2s2), merge them into a logical volume group, and them create logical volumes within that group. You can get the UUID of the logical volume group with:

```
lvguuid="$(diskutil info /dev/disk2s2 | awk '/LVG UUID:/ {print $3}')"
```

Unfortunately, you then have to figure out the logical volume UUID, and I think to do that you have to run `diskutil cs list` (maybe with the `-plist` option), and parse through the mess that results, looking for the logical volume(s) in that group. Ick.